# Improving wifi antenna reception/transmission

Tags: wireless-networking

Here's the scenario:

I work in Building A.  I had no internet access but a friend in Building B (across the parking lot was awesome and willing to share his connection.  So, I took an old Verizon Actiontec MI424WR wireless router and put it in Building B.  I configured it as an AP by disabling DHCP and assigning it a static IP.  It IS working but the reception in Building A is very poor due mainly to the fact that it is a corrugated steel building.  This causes my throughput to be similar to dial up.  If I walk outside with my laptop, the performance significantly increases as the connection strength does and, obviously, gets better the closer I walk to Building B.

I've done a bit of research but I'm not putting all of this together into a solution so I Was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction.  Here are two considerations:

1) Purchase some sort of AP, Router or WIfi extender and mount the antenna externally on Building A.  But, now I still have an antenna on the other side of a steel wall.  So, this new device may be able to communicate with the Actiontec router located in Building B but now my wireless devices in Building A may have difficulty communicating with the new extender device.

2) I've looked into "cantenna" a bit.  However, I can't figure out what this set up would look like.  i.e. Would I replace the antenna on the router in Building B with a cantenna and shoot it right at Building A?  Or would I get some sort of AP for Building A and use a cantenna aimed at Building B?

3) Possible replace the Actiontec router in Building B with some sort of high end router which may be able to transmit a more powerful signal?

My knowledge of this is limited as you may see, but hopefully I've described the scope of the problem accurately.

Thanks in advance!

Oh, and Comcast wants to charge me a ton of money to install cable service to my building - that's why I don't just get my own internet connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is effectively asking for an opinion and is too broad for our Q&A format. For guidance on what to avoid when posting a question, see the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already headed in the right direction for this problem.

It really looks like you are looking for a point to point wireless bridge. The wireless access points are going to stay in same place, the outside of your building is made of steel and hard to penetrate, so having a cantenna on the outside connect to a wireless router on the inside is a good solution.

My advice would be to buy a router to turn into a wireless bridge (the DD-WRT firmware is a good way to handle this), and connect a cantenna to the output of the router. Place the cantenna out the outside pointed in the direction of the AP, and find a hole in the wall for the antenna pigtail to connect to the router on the inside.

This solution relies on a lot of experimentation and general hacker-y

There are also commercial solution for wireless point to point bridges that you may want to look into. They will probably end up costing you more, but will save you a bit of a headache. A quick google led me here: http://www.proxim.com/products/point-to-point-backhaul

There are lots of vendors to look at.

Comment: So, if in my building, I set up a router and use an externally mounted cantenna aimed at my neighbors building, then what do my wireless devices inside my building connect to?  Or would they be able to connect to the cantenna router despite it's shooting the signal in the opposite direction?

Comment: You would have to buy another wireless access point. The router that the cantenna would be connected to would be dedicated to receiving the wireless signal, and relaying it to the wired network.

Comment: Here is some good information about the type of setup I'm talking about. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge